# How can I dynamically create objects in django/python?

Tags: python, django, dynamic

In my code I have many if/elif statements like this:

```
if type == "cat":
    vote = VoteCat (
        user = user,
        cat_id = thing_id )
    vote.save()
elif type == "dog":
    vote = VoteDog (
        user = user,
        dog_id = thing_id )
    vote.save()
```

What would be a good way to change my code to get rid of the if statements and instantiate the object I need dynamically? The code I am hoping I can write would accomplish the same as above but look more like this:

```
AnimalVote = get_animalvote_by_type(type)
AnimalVote.user = user
AnimalVote.assign_animal_id(thing_id)
AnimalVote.save()
```

Comment: if i'm understanding your question correctly, perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to have an AnimalVote model with a field specifying what type of animal it is.

Comment: Since you're using django how about a custom objects manager?

Comment: I've thought doing it your way Kapura but thought that it may not scale as well as I add many different kinds of Animals that have slightly different behaviors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest translation is:

```
types = dict('cat' = CatType, 'dog' = DogType)
newobj = types[type](user = user, cat_id = thing_id)
```

Obviously, this relies on the types taking the same parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the simple, quick answer. I feel like I should have known I could do it this way.

Comment: @tedtoy It's not entirely obvious until you know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Classes in Python are objects, so you can just have a map mapping names to classes:

```
animal_type_map = {'cat': VoteCat, 'dog': VoteDog}
```

Then you can use `animal_type_map[type]` just as you would use `VoteCat` or `VoteDog`.